# How to find the indexes of minimum value for each row of a dataframe?

Tags: r, matrix, minimum

Assume I have a dataframe `df` like

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x    1    2    7    1
y    1    5    1    5
```

I would like to find the indexes of minimum value for each row of `df`. My expected result is

```
YES NO NO  NO YES
YES NO YES NO No
```

I tried

```
x <- c(1, 2, 7, 1)
y <- c(1, 5, 1, 5)
df <- rbind(x, y)
apply(df, 1, which.min)
```

but it does not work. Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: Try `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x == min(x)))`

Comment: Thank you so much again @akrun!

Comment: Or `df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(-df))] == df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN =1`), compare the elements in the row with `min` of the row

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x == min(x)))
```

-output

```
#  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#x TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#y TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or make it compact with `rowMins` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
df == rowMins(df)
#  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#x TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#y TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or if we want to stick with `base R` and use a vectorized option then `pmin` is another way (after converting the `matrix` to `data.frame`)

```
df == do.call(pmin, as.data.frame(df))
```

Comment: I just saw your `pmin` approach at the bottom, much better than my version with `Reduce` :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding It's okay.  I think that is a nice alternative.  Also, there are some functions that work in `do.call` and not in `Reduce`, viceversa

Comment: I added a comment in my answer to emphasize the benefits of your solution by applying `do.call`

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
#Code
X==apply(X,1, min)
```

Output:

```
X==apply(X,1, min)
    V2    V3    V4    V5
x TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
y TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
X <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 5L), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("x", "y"), c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `Reduce` + `pmin` (better to use `do.call` (rather than `Reduce`) as [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743516/12158757) presented when more columns are involved, from the perspective of speed since `Reduce` would be much slower.)

```
Reduce(pmin, data.frame(df)) == df
```

gives

```
  [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
x TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
y TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```